# JPA Issue with WAS 6.1

Tags: java, jpa, websphere, websphere-6.1

I have installed an application on WAS 6.1 (through WID 6.1) and getting following exception while running the app.

> Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: class declares generator name "system-uuid", but uses the AUTO generation type.  The only valid generator names under AUTO are "uuid-hex" and "uuid-string".

I have changed databases but still the problem persists. The class do declares `Authorization_ID` to be System-UUID but it has worked fine for WAS7. Please provide your comments. Here is a snippet of the class:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")
@javax.persistence.Column(name="AUTHORIZATION_ID")
@XmlID 
@XmlAttribute
public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
```

Comment: Best bet would be to file an PMR to IBM ...

Comment: Are you using the WAS 6.1 EJB 3.0 Feature Pack ? (For getting JPA support)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. This was because WAS was using it's own openJPA implementation of JPA while I intended it to use hibernate.

Resolved this by removing the WAS feature pack for EJB 3.0

Hope this helps.